# exceeds the maximum allowed database size when export database oracle 18c

Tags: oracle, export, oracle-18c

I have worked on Oracle Database 18c Express Edition, while I try to export database schema by using expd command, I have an issues

> ORA-12954: The request exceeds the maximum allowed database size of 12 GB.

Full log:

```
Export: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Sep 20 15:48:06 2019
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production

Warning: Oracle Data Pump operations are not typically needed when connected to the root or seed of a container database.

Starting "TEST_DATA"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_02":  TEST_DATA/******** schemas=TEST_DATA directory=TEST_DATA dumpfile=TEST_DATA.dpdmp logfile=TEST_DATA.log FILESIZE=50GB
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/STATISTICS/MARKER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/DEFAULT_ROLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/COMMENT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
. . exported "TEST_DATA"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01"        270.9 KB    1464 rows
. . exported "TEST_DATA"."ZP_CR60071"                      0 KB       0 rows
ORA-39126: Worker unexpected fatal error in KUPW$WORKER.UNLOAD_DATA [TABLE_DATA:"TEST_DATA"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_02"]
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 2
ORA-12954: The request exceeds the maximum allowed database size of 12 GB.

ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPW$WORKER", line 12372
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 39134
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 38422
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 37316
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 15610
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 1785
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 15279
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 15410
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 37251
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 38141
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 38570
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 39116
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPW$WORKER", line 4200

----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
000007FF2F785540     32868  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER.WRITE_ERROR_INFORMATION
000007FF2F785540     12400  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER.DETERMINE_FATAL_ERROR
000007FF2F785540      4617  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER.UNLOAD_DATA
000007FF2F785540     13474  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER.DISPATCH_WORK_ITEMS
000007FF2F785540      2410  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER.MAIN
000007FF2BA73120         2  anonymous block

KUPW: Method: 1
KUPW: Parallel: 1
KUPW: Creation level: 0
KUPW: Sequence number: 0
BULK COLLECT
BULK COLLECT
KUPW: In procedure BUILD_OBJECT_STRINGS - non-base info
KUPW: In PROCESS_TABLE_DATA_METRICS
DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS
KUPW: In procedure DETERMINE_FATAL_ERROR with ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 2
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 39134
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 38422
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 37316
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 15610
ORA-12954: The request exceeds the maximum allowed database size of 12 GB.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 1785
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 15279
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 15410
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 37251
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 38141
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 38570
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 39116

Job "TEST_DATA"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_02" stopped due to fatal error at Fri Sep 20 15:51:02 2019 elapsed 0 00:02:55
```

Does anyone know the reason and how to fix?

Thanks in advances!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600808/full-oracle-10g-xe-database-cant-be-exported

Comment: Use exp command. Expdp needs extra espace to create a master table.

Comment: Actually this is probably a limitation of the Express (free) edition.  `exp` is an old utility, and in DataPump `expdp` command, the master table does not use much space.